# Combobox binding to a dictionary

Tags: c#, xaml, binding

I have two properties:

```
public bool Condition{get;set;}

public string ConditionString{
get
{
  if(Condition)
    { return  FirstString;   }
  else
   {return SecondString;   }

}
set{
_conditionString = value;
  }}
```

I created a property to use to bind with my combobox:

```
public Dictionary<String, bool> Conditions {
get{ 
    Dictionary<String, bool> conditions = new Dictionary<String, bool>();
    conditions.add(FirstString, true);
    conditions.add(SecondString, false);
    return conditions;
   }
 }
```

Now I have my combobox and I do the following in Xaml:

```
 <ComboBox 
 ItemsSource="{Binding Conditions}"
 DisplayMemberPath="Key"
 SelectedValuePath="Value"
 SelectedItem = "{Binding Condition}" 
/>
```

What I want is to display the strings as options to the end user, which is working fine. However, I want the selected item to set the `Condition`. However, this does not happen and I don't know why. Also, I want either of the values to be selected by default.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how, maybe just try to add Mode = TwoWay like this:

SelectedItem="{Binding Condition, Mode=TwoWay}"